# pandas fetching rows after set_index

Tags: pandas

I have a PD dataframe as follows:

```
Model   TireSize   GasTank
Honda    25         20
Toyota   22         15
```

I want to make the Model the index of the DF and return the `TireSize` and `GasTank` as values when I call `df['Honda']`
Hoever after doing a `df.set_index('Model', inplace=True)` I get an key error when I try to access the data.

Specifically I am getting
`` IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices ``
Thanks!

Comment: `df.loc['Honda']`, `df['Honda']` give you the **column** named "Honda".

Comment: can you give us the code, where the dataframe is defined. I used the ´set_index´ comand and it works just fine

Comment: the df.loc['Honda'] worked perfectly! Thanks! can you make it the answer and I will accept?